# When did Clark Kent [post-Crisis and New 52] meet and become the inspiration for the Legion of Superheroes?

Tags: story-identification, dc, superman, legion-of-superheroes

This is more a question of story identification, rather than checking on canon. Pre-crisis, Superboy is noted for becoming friends with the Legion's main trio, Cosmic Boy, Chameleon Boy and Saturn Girl, in his mid-teens; they traveled back in time to meet the person who inspired their creation, and thus gave Clark some fellow super-powered teens to pal around with. However, Post-Crisis, Clark didn't begin his super career until well into adulthood.

In the early 2000s Superman series *Secret Origin*, a retelling of the Superman mythos combining elements from Post-Crisis, Pre-Crisis and whole new takes on older stories, including revamping elements from the golden age [Superboy, Krypto, and the Legion, for instance]. So I'm wondering if there is a story, both Post-Crisis and New 52, which explains when they met, and how the Legion came to be.

Would anyone be able to elaborate?

Comment: Minor nitpick.  Chameleon boy wasn't part of the "main trio" .  That was Lightning Lad.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt You right, no doubt. The first Legion comic i ever read with superboy was years ago, and Chams was really funny in that one, so it always sticks in my memory.

Comment: Probably the one where Cham impersonated Clark Kent so he and Superboy could appear side by side and make Lana Lang flip out.  Sorry I can't answer your question.  I'm somewhat of a Legion buff, but all pre-Crisis.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt I appreciate the answer either way, friend. Thank you for the input

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but ... I've been reading recently the *Superman by Grant Morrison Omnibus* that collects Action Comics vol.2 #0-18 and Action Comics Annual #1

In **Action Comics vol.2 #6** - by Grant Morrison, Andy Kubert, John Dell et al - the first encounter between Clark Kent and the three founding members of the Legion is retold in a flashback.

[From the DC Fandom Wiki](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_2_6) entry corresponding to that issue

> Superman recalls a time when he was just 13 years old, and he'd helped
> his father to subdue their neighbour's rogue bull. Jonathan marvelled
> at the boy's strength, which set Clark to thinking about his alien
> heritage. Jonathan believed that the rocket was a lifeboat, meant to
> send Clark where he could do some good. Clark agreed, wondering if his
> parents might ever come back for him. He suspected that they would
> not, and Jonathan commented that without any knowledge of his family,
> it would be up to Clark to determine for himself what the S-shield
> meant. Later that night, **Clark noticed that he was being watched by
> three strangers. As it happened, it was Garth, Imra, and Rokk,
> observing the boy would become a hero to them. They introduced
> themselves, and became fast friends.**

[image: Action Comics vol.2 6 cover by Andy Kubert]

Comment: Given that this is the **New 52,** I'm guessing this may not be canon (any longer?) Either way, its a valid answer to look up. Thank you, Friend.